# RxJS count how long hovered over button

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I am able to log to the console every time someone hovers over a button, but how would I could how many seconds this had happened for and aggregate the total?

```
var result = document.getElementById('result');
var source = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(result, 'mouseover');
var subscription = source.subscribe(
   function (x) {
    console.log('Hovered!');
   }
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I am understanding your requirements correctly, You would need to check when the mouse also leaves the element as well, and then use and operator like `scan` to sum the total. A relatively simple way to do this would be get a timestamp of the `mouseover` and then sample on the `mouseout` event:

```
var result = document.getElementById('result');
var mouseOver = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(result, 'mouseover');
var mouseOut  = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(result, 'mouseout');

mouseOver
  //Get the time of the mouseover event
  .timestamp()
  //Don't emit until the mouseOut triggers
  .sample(mouseOut)
  //Extract only the timestamp value
  .pluck('timestamp')
  //Get a new timestamp (remember this is *after* mouse out)
  .timestamp()
  //Compute the timeinterval
  .map(x => x.timestamp - x.value)
//Add the new time interval to the running total
.scan((total, diff) => total += diff, 0)
.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an alternate solution I came up with, not optimal but worth sharing for the technique.

```
var counter = 0;

var source = Rx.Observable.interval(100)
  .map(() => '.');

var display = document.querySelector("#display");
var toggle = document.querySelector("#toggle");

var hover = false;

var mouseOver = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(toggle, "mouseenter")
  .map(e => {hover=true;});
var mouseOut = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(toggle, "mouseleave")
  .map(e => {hover=false;});

mouseOver //.filter(x => true)
  .flatMapLatest(() => source.takeUntil(mouseOut))
  .subscribe(x => {counter += 1; display.innerText = counter});
```